# Removable discontinuity for $C^1$ functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with uniformly bounded partials.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on the following question: Say I have a function $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\})$ with uniformly bounded partials, why must $f$ admit a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

My thought was that to show it was uniformly continuous (which might follow by proving some Lipschitz-type bound), but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right: $f$ is Lipschitz in $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$. The proof consists of three steps:

**Mean Value Theorem**. 
Let $M$ be an upper bound for $|f_x|,|f_y|$. Consider a horizontal line segment $I\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ of length $\ell$. The restriction of $f$ to $I$ is a function of one variable $x$, and its derivative is bounded by $M$. By the mean value theorem, the difference of the values of $f$ at the endpoints of $I$ is at most $M\ell$. The same applies to vertical segments as well.

**Geometric construction.** Given any two points $A=(x_1,y_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2)$, we can find a polygonal line which

- begins at  $A$ and ends at $B$
- is contained in $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\} $
- consists of vertical and horizontal segments
- has total length at most $2|AB|$

In most cases, two sides of rectangle in which $A$ and $B$ are opposite vertices will work. But if  $A$ and $B$ are on the different halves of the same coordinate axis, use three sides of a thin rectangle in which $A$ and $B$ are adjacent vertices.

**Generalized triangle inequality.** Apply  the mean value theorem to each segment  of the polygonal line constructed in the previous step, and combine the results using the triangle inequality. The conclusion is $|f(A)-f(B)|\le 2M|AB|$, which is the Lipschitz condition.

---

*Remark*. The same idea can be used to show that every closed set of length zero is removable for $f$.